# Android SVG and Viewport

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

I have an SVG and it always seems the w/h (100/100) is always the same as the viewport sizes.  If I change the viewport to be less it always starts at 0,0 and goes to 50,50

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="100dp"
android:height="100dp"
android:viewportWidth="100"
android:viewportHeight="100">
```

[image: size 100x100, viewport 100x100]

here is half the sizes and you get 1/4 the image, the top left.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="100dp"
android:height="100dp"
android:viewportWidth="50"
android:viewportHeight="50">
```

[image: size 100x100, viewport 50x50]

What if I wanted to have the viewport take it from the middle and cut off the padding?  Like this.  How would I do this.

[image: What I want centered viewport]

Comment: Adjust the viewBox attributes values.

Comment: There is no viewbox in android vector.

Comment: I've removed the androidsvg tag and added android-vectordrawable

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of solutions:

The simplest is probably to load the SVG into a vector editor and move the shapes up into the corner; resize the document; then save out the new SVG

Or you could manually add `android:translateX` and `android:translateY`  attribute to the elements you want to move. I can't tell you which elements you need to modify (or by how much) because you haven't posted the whole file.  You'll also need to update the `android:viewportWidth` and `android:viewportHeight` accordingly.